# why does Java allow generic array declaration?

Tags: java, generic-programming, generic-list

I know that array generic array creation is not allowed because arrays need to know their type at run-time but since generic erase their type information at run-time it is not possible to create generic array.
But how come it allows generic array declaration as follow :

```
private E[] genericArray;// this line does not prevent the class from compiling

private E[] genericArrayTwo= new E[][10];// this line prevents the class from compiling
```

Comment: Why would it not be allowed? Note that a field declaration of an array is initialized to `null` by default, so there's no need to know the element type.

Answer (score 1):

```java
private E[] genericArray;// this line does not prevent the class from compiling

private E[] genericArrayTwo= new E[][10];// this line prevents the class from compiling
```

- Your first example was compile time evaluation to ensure proper
  typing.  Simply says that this array may contain something of type E.
- Your second example would need to be executed at run time when E has
  already been erased.  Can't create an array of type E because E is no longer available.

Allowing generic array declarations ensures that appropriate types are matched at compile time.

```java
      Integer[] ints1 = null;
      String[] str1 = null;

      // both requires cast or it won't compile
      Integer[] ints = (Integer[])doSomething1(ints1);
      String[] str = (String[])doSomething1(str1);

      //but that could result in a runtime error if miscast.
      //That type of error might not appear for a long time

      // Generic method caters to all array types.
      // no casting required.
      ints = doSomething2(ints1);
      str = doSomething2(str1);

   }

   public static Object[] doSomething1(Object[] array) {
      return array;
   }

   public static <T> T[] doSomething2(T[] array) {
      return array;
   }
```

It allows examples such as the following:

```java
public <T> void copy(List<T> list, T[] array) {
   for (T e : array) {
      list.add(e);
   }
}
```

You could then assign a value from either the list or the array to some variable of type T without getting a class cast exception or without having to to an `instanceof` test.

Comment: "Allowing generic array declarations ensures that appropriate types are matched at compile time" could you please explain this point?

Answer (score 0):

If `E` is a formal generic of the current class, yes you can do that :

```
List<E> e = new ArrayList<E>();
```

but you cannot do that :

```
E[] e = new E[10];
```

But declaring the `E[] e` variable makes sense all the same.

because no one prevents you from valuing the array from the client side that knows the real type of the array :

```
Foo<E> class{        
    private E[] array;
    Foo(E[] array) {
        this.array = array;
    }
}
```

And to use it as :

```
Foo<String> foo = new Foo<>(new String[] { "a", "b" });
```

Or as alternative you could also pass the class of the array to instantiate from the client side :

```
Foo<String> foo = new Foo<>(String.class);
```

So you see that declaring `E[] array` is not so helpless.